# Select tableview cell to show and hide an UIView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a UIView, lets call it "iconView", it is in a cell. It is hidden by default. I want, when user tap on the cell it will be shown (isHidden = false) and when user tap again, it will be hidden (isHidden = true)
here is my code, the problem is, it will be shown after tapping, but it wont be hidden after tapping again.
Your help will be appreciated.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 1:
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 1:
            if isIconViewShown  {
                iconView.isHidden = true
            }
            iconViewShown.isHidden = !iconView.isHidden
            isIconViewShown = true
        default:
            break
        }
  }
```

Comment: note you have 2 oultets `iconViewShown`  and `iconView` so consider exactly which 1 the problem with

Answer (score 0):

Why have extra variables to keep track of?

Just toggle `iconView.isHidden`.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 1:
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 1:
            iconView.isHidden = !iconView.isHidden
            iconViewShown.isHidden = !iconView.isHidden
            // or maybe iconViewShown.isHidden = iconView.isHidden
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```